# Hot Module Replacement breaks w/ custom loader

Tags: javascript, preprocessor, webpack, babeljs

I wrote a CSS pre-processor that accepts JSON as its source.. and a webpack loader that dynamically generates JSON and gives it to the pre-processor.

For example `header.gss`:

```
import config from 'views/header.config.json';

export default function Header() {
  return {
    header: {
      position: 'fixed',
      height: config.height,
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
      _a: {
        color: '#333',
        $hover: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Renders to:

```
.header { position: fixed; height: 50px; background-color: #eee; }
.header > a { color: #eee; }
.header > a:hover { color: #000; }
```

Generating JSON dynamically makes this extremely powerful. Unfortunately w/ 50+ stylesheets the build process takes ~12 seconds and is a development hindrance.

HMR is the solution, it's working for SASS & ES7 JS but not my custom parser:

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
[WDS] Nothing changed.
```

The webpack server is creating new bundles but no hot updates. Here's my loader source:

```
var queryString = require('query-string');

var root = __dirname.split('/').slice(0, -2).join('/');
process.env.NODE_PATH = root + ':' + root + '/src';
require('module').Module._initPaths();
require('babel/register')();

module.exports = function() {
  if (this.cacheable) this.cacheable();
  var options = queryString.parse(this.query);
  var jsonToCss = require('../gss/jsonToCss');
  var config;
  try {
    config = require(options.c);
  } catch (e) {
    config = 'Could not resolve ' + options.c;
  }
  const css = jsonToCss(require(this.resourcePath)(config || {}));
  return css;
};
```

It's clearly a hack so webpack partially breaking is understandable. But I don't want it to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` caches files. Add:

```
delete require.cache[this.resourcePath];
```

Immediately after your require.